# CompareTo using more than 1 attributes using Apache Commons CompareToBuilder

Tags: java

I would like to sort an ArrayList of objects in Java 6. I would like the display the selected == TRUE at the top, then by billingConditionName in alphabetical order.

```
public int compare(IBillingConditionDTO o1, IBillingConditionDTO o2) {
      return new org.apache.commons.lang.builder.CompareToBuilder()
            .append(o1.getSelected(), o2.getSelected())
            .append(o1.getBillingConditionName(), o2.getBillingConditionName())
            .toComparison();
```

Result is those which are selected == TRUE are displayed first and within this list, it is then sorted alphabetically.

Problem is those which are selected == FALSE are not sorted alphabetically.

Sample result:

```
Selected, BillingConditionName
true, containerSize
true, containerType
false, pod
false, transType
false, freight
```

I would like the result to be:

```
Selected, BillingConditionName
true, containerSize
true, containerType
false, freight
false, pod
false, transType
```

Please help. thanks.

Comment: Please show how you are sorting your objects, and how you use the compare method you've written.

Comment: As false < true, but your strings are sorted in ascending order, I don't think you are doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: With `CompareToBuilder` you `append` the fields that determine your sort in the order of highest priority to lowest priority - the first append is compared first AND only if the values compare == 0, will the second, third, fourth, ... Nth level compares take effect.    I note that after BIllingConditionName none of the other values are being considered ..  If they are important to the result then they need to be.

Comment: @MrR what the OP is saying is that when selected is false in both records, then the name is not being used. There are no other fields.

Comment: @AppleT looks like you need to supply more data - I've attached an answer showing that what you are describing isn't happening - AND - it shows you might need to consider more than the first 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Translated the OP into a bigger snippet to see if the problem is reproducible AND it isn't.

```java
package abuzz.kiosk.server.portal.media.schedule;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.CompareToBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;

public class SortTest {

    public boolean selected;
    public String conditionName;
    public String lastCondition;

    SortTest(final boolean selected, final String conditionName, final String lastCondition) {
        this.selected = selected;
        this.conditionName = conditionName;
        this.lastCondition = lastCondition;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE); // append(selected).append(conditionName).append(lastCondition).toString();
    }

    public static Comparator<SortTest> toComp = new Comparator<SortTest>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(SortTest o1, SortTest o2) {
            return new CompareToBuilder().append(!o1.selected, !o2.selected)
                    .append(o1.conditionName, o2.conditionName).toComparison();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortTest[] ip = new SortTest[] { new SortTest(true, "A", "Blah"),
                new SortTest(false, "A", "Bingo"),
                new SortTest(true, "2A", "Blah"),
                new SortTest(true, "1B", "Blah"),
                new SortTest(true, "1A", "Blah"),
                new SortTest(true, "1A", "Apple"),
                new SortTest(true, "1A", "Cat"),
                new SortTest(false, "B", "Bingo"),
                new SortTest(false, "A", "Apple")
                };

        // Print out ip
        System.out.println("In");
        dump(ip);
        System.out.println();

        // Sort
        Arrays.parallelSort(ip, toComp);
        
        // Post sort printout.
        System.out.println("Out");
        dump(ip);
    }

    static void dump(SortTest[] ip) {
        for (final SortTest curr : ip) {
            System.out.println(curr.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

gives this output

```
In
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=A,lastCondition=Blah]
SortTest[selected=false,conditionName=A,lastCondition=Bingo]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=2A,lastCondition=Blah]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=1B,lastCondition=Blah]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=1A,lastCondition=Blah]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=1A,lastCondition=Apple]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=1A,lastCondition=Cat]
SortTest[selected=false,conditionName=B,lastCondition=Bingo]
SortTest[selected=false,conditionName=A,lastCondition=Apple]

Out
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=1A,lastCondition=Blah]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=1A,lastCondition=Apple]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=1A,lastCondition=Cat]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=1B,lastCondition=Blah]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=2A,lastCondition=Blah]
SortTest[selected=true,conditionName=A,lastCondition=Blah]
SortTest[selected=false,conditionName=A,lastCondition=Bingo]
SortTest[selected=false,conditionName=A,lastCondition=Apple]
SortTest[selected=false,conditionName=B,lastCondition=Bingo]
```

notice how select=true are first, and condition name are sorted secondarily (ascending for same selected=X, and the rest of the data - well it's random because when two objects are the same on the first two values - the code will need to fallback to something else if the last condition matters.